# How to change the Process Template in DevOps Server 2020 for existing Projects

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfs-process-template

We are currently using Team Foundation Server 2017 and want to migrate to DevOps Server 2020,
We created new DevOps Server 2020 and created new process template, we modified the built-in Agile process template by adding a new workflow and new columns to some work items.

I need to know how to migrate the old projects on TFS 2017 to DevOps 2020 and change the process templates to the new the process template we created.

Thanks

Comment: You don't migrate the projects. You upgrade TFS, or migrate the entire project collection. Updating process templates is going to be a manual process that you'd have to script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to migrate the old projects on TFS 2017 to DevOps 2020

For this requirement, we cannot migrate only the project to another new Azure DevOps server.

This feature is not supported.

Currently we can migrate the project collection to the new server.

For more detailed steps, you can refer to this doc: [Move a project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=azure-devops-2020)

> Change the process templates to the new the process template we created.

According to this requirement, you need to determine whether the process on your Azure DevOps Server 2020 is inherited or XML.

As far as I know ,  TFS 2017 only supports XML process.

If you are using XML process collection in the Azure DevOps Server 2020, you can export the XML process and import the process to the migrated Collection.

If you are using inherited process collection in the Azure DevOps Server 2020, I am afraid that you can't change the old XML process to the new inherited  process.

For more detailed info, you can refer to my another ticket: [How to upgrade a Team project to use the Inheritance model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253890/how-to-upgrade-a-team-project-to-use-the-inheritance-model)